# SQL server numeros aleatorios

Tags: sql-server

Neste codigo só retorna um valor, preciso de uma lista de valores, como faço?

```
 declare @letras varchar(max) = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXZ1234567890'
    declare @tamanho int = 10
    ;with cte as (
        select
            1 as contador,
            substring(@letras, 1 + (abs(checksum(newid())) % len(@letras)), 1) as letra
        union all
        select
            contador + 1,
            substring(@letras, 1 + (abs(checksum(newid())) % len(@letras)), 1)
        from cte where contador < @tamanho)
    --select * from cte option (maxrecursion 0)
    select (
        select '' + letra from cte
        for xml path(''), type, root('txt')
        ).value ('/txt[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Bom, sua necessidade é retornar uma lista de valores aleatórios, para isso adaptei criando uma tabela temporaria definindo um loop para linha alimentada:

Pode testar em qualquer banco..

```
DECLARE @Retorno char(100)

DECLARE @total int = 1000
        ,@linha INT = 1

DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Valor VARCHAR(MAX)
)

WHILE (@linha < @total)
BEGIN
SET @Retorno = (
    SELECT 
        c1 AS [text()]
    FROM(
        SELECT TOP (1000) c1
        FROM(
            VALUES
              ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'),
              ('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'),
              ('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z'), ('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'),
              ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9')  
            ) AS T1(c1)
    ORDER BY ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
    ) AS T2
FOR XML PATH('')
)

    INSERT INTO @table VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(@Retorno)))

    SET @linha = @linha + 1
END


SELECT Valor FROM @table
```

Obs: Caso queira aumentar o numero de loops, basta você aumentar o valor da variável `@total`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Só tenho duas duvidas, primeiramente, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Enfim, Eu consigo fixar um valor, por exemplo, quero apenas 10 caracteres, e não se pode apenas LETRAS, ou apenas NUMEROS, e nem repetidos.

Comment: Obrigado meu caro, segue o script na resposta atualizado, conforme solicitado.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas Lira, eu Incrementei conforme solicitado para filtrar a quantidade de caracters para retorno, Retornar só números ou só letras ou todos.

Crie essa função:

```
     CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRemoveCaracteresNaoNumericos](@Temp varchar(1000))
         RETURNS varchar(1000)

         AS

        BEGIN
        --Defini escala dos numeros
        DECLARE @Manter AS varchar(50) = '%[^0-9]%'

        WHILE PATINDEX(@Manter, @Temp) > 0

          SET @Temp = STUFF(@Temp, PATINDEX(@Manter, @Temp), 1, '')

        RETURN @Temp

      END
```

Agora utilize o script atualizado:

```
    DECLARE @Retorno CHAR(100)
    -- Digitar tipo de retorno -> 'texto' / 
    -- 'numeros' / 'todos'
    DECLARE @type VARCHAR(10) = 'texto' 
    DECLARE @total int = 1000
    ,@linha INT = 1
    DECLARE @QtdeCaracter INT = 3 -- Defini qtde de caracters que ira retornar

    DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
      Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
      Valor VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

   WHILE (@linha < @total)
   BEGIN
      SET @Retorno = (
                      SELECT 
                      c1 AS [text()]
                      FROM(
                          SELECT TOP (1000) c1
                          FROM(
                          VALUES
                                ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'),
                           ('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'),
                           ('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z'), ('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'),
                           ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9')  
                     ) AS T1(c1)
         ORDER BY ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
         ) AS T2
        FOR XML PATH('')
       )

       INSERT INTO @table 
       VALUES 
       (LTRIM
       (RTRIM(
            (SELECT 
                  CASE 
                    WHEN (@type = 'Numeros') 
                        THEN dbo.fnRemoveCaracteresNaoNumericos(@Retorno) 
                    WHEN (@type = 'texto') 
                        THEN  
             REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                              REPLACE(@Retorno, 0, ''), 1, ''), 2, ''), 3, ''), 4, 
             ''), 5, ''), 6, ''), 7, ''), 8, ''), 9, '')
                          ELSE @Retorno
                      END))))

                       SET @linha = @linha + 1
                       END

            --Distinct para nao repetir os valores, com funcão rtrim e ltrim para 
            -- limpar espacos em branco
           SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(valor, 1, @QtdeCaracter))) [Valor]
           FROM @table
           ORDER BY Valor
```